# how can I read a value from an XML-formatted web page

Tags: python, xml

What I am trying to do is the following. There is this web page: http://xml.buienradar.nl .

From that, I want to extract a value every n minutes, preferably with Python. Let's say the windspeed at the Gilze-Rijen station. That is located on this page at:

```
<buienradarnl>.<weergegevens>.<actueel_weer>.<weerstations>.<weerstation id="6350">.<windsnelheidMS>4.80</windsnelheidMS>
```

Now, I can find loads of questions with answers that use Python to read a local XML file. But, I would rather not need to `wget` or `curl` this page every couple of minutes.

Obviously, I'm not very familiar with this.

There *must* be a very easy way to do this. The answer either escapes me or is drowned in all the answers that solve problems with a local file.

Answer (score 2):

I would use urllib2 and BeautifulSoup.

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = Request("http://xml.buienradar.nl/")
response = urlopen(req)
output = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(output)

print soup.prettify()
```

Then you can traverse the output like you were suggesting:

```
soup.buienradarnl.weergegevens (etc)
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work. The `soup = Beautiful...` line takes 5s to complete. Any possibilities to improve on that?